# Removing the first half of the entries in LinkedHashMap other than looping

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, linkedhashmap

I was going to use `Hashtable` but some existing answer said only `LinkedHashMap` preserve the insertion order. So, it seems that I can get the insertion order with the `entries` or `keys` properties.

My question is, when the map has n elements, if I want to remove the first n/2 elements, is there a better way than looping through the `keys` and repeatedly calling `remove(key)`? That is, something like this

```
val a = LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>();
val n = 10;
for(i in 1 .. n)
{
    a[i] = i*10;
}
a.removeRange(0,n/2);
```

instead of

```
val a = LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>();
val n = 10;
for(i in 1 .. n)
{
    a[i] = i*10;
}

var i = 0;
var keysToRemove= ArrayList<Int>();
for(k in a.keys)
{
    if(i >= n/2)
        break;
    else
        i++

    keysToRemove.add(k);
}

for(k in keysToRemove)
{
    a.remove(k);
}
```

The purpose of this is that I use the map as a cache, and when the cache is full, I want to purge the oldest half of the entries. I do not have to use `LinkedHashMap` as long as I can:

- Find the value using a key, efficiently.
- Remove a range of entries at once.

Comment: Why not use an LRUCache? It purges the least recently used entries automatically. There's plenty of implementations out there so no coding required on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method in the class that makes this possible. The source code doesn't have any operations for ranges of keys or entries. Since the linking is built on top of the HashMap logic, individual entries still have to be individuatlly found by a hashed key lookup to remove them, so being able to remove a range couldn't be done faster in a LinkedHashMap, which is unlike the analogy of a LinkedList to an ArrayList.

For simpler code that's equivalent to what you're doing:

```
a.keys.take(a.size / 2).forEach(a::remove)
```

If you don't want to use a library for a cache set, LinkedHashSet is designed so you can easily build your own by subclassing. For instance, a basic one that simply removes the oldest entry when you add elements above a certain collection size:

```
class CacheHashMap<K, V>(private var maxSize: Int): LinkedHashMap<K, V>() {
    override fun removeEldestEntry(eldest: MutableMap.MutableEntry<K, V>?): Boolean =
        size == maxSize
}
```

Also, if you set `accessOrder` to true in your constructor call, it orders by last used to most recently used entry, which might be more apt for your situation than insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry I missed the part about using this as an LRU cache, for that use case, TreeMap will not be suitable.

---

If insertion order is just incidental for you, and what you want is in fact the actual order of comparable keys, you should use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead.

However, the specific use case of removing half the keys might not be supported directly. You will rather find methods to remove keys below/above a certain value, and get the highest/lowest keys.

Comment: No, TreeMap doesn't preserve insertion order.

Comment: @k314159 it's not insertion order, it's natural order of keys, yes. I'll add the precision.